# Tab bar setup in app delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In order to change a tab bar item when selected, I have setup my tab bar images inside the app delegate. The  code I use is below-

```
let firstTab = tabBar.items![0]
    firstTab.image! = UIImage(named: "map-pin")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    firstTab.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "map-pin-bold")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

This works fine although at the beginning of my app. The problem is I have a tutorial and on the last page of the tutorial, I segue to my tab bar controller and the produces a bug. Instead of the tab bar being white, it is a greyish color for the items not selected. Furthermore, the icon does not change to a bold when selected. I am finding it tricky to overcome this problem as the only viable option I see is to go through the app delegate again.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about starting your app with the tab bar controller already loaded and have tutorial be presented modally from the first VC of the TBC.  When the tutorial is done, simply dismiss it to transition to your TBC.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean the tutorial VC's would be tab bar items

Comment: No.  Presented modally, the tutorial's VC's would completely cover the tab bar view.